# VLC picture_t to IplImage and IplImage to picture_t

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, plugins, vlc

I'm trying to write VLC video filter using openCV to normalize video.
And I'm having troubles with VLC `picture_t` converting to `IplImage` and back to `picture_t`. IplImage is needed for transform to Mat and proceed with openCV tools. Couldn't find the solution elsewhere, so asking for help here.
The main function for transforming images is:

```
static picture_t *FilterNormalizeOpenCV( filter_t *p_filter, picture_t *p_pic )
{
Mat frame1;
IplImage* p_img1;
video_format_t fmt_out, fmt_in;
int i_planes = p_pic->i_planes;
CvSize sz = cvSize(abs(p_pic->format.i_width), abs(p_pic->format.i_height));
CvPoint pt1, pt2;
filter_sys_t *p_sys = p_filter->p_sys;

if ((!p_pic)) {
    msg_Err( p_filter, "no image array" );
    printf ("\n\n %s \n\n", "No p pic!!!");
    return NULL;
}

i_planes = p_pic->i_planes;
if (i_planes<1) {
    printf ("\n\n %s \n\n", "No image planes!!!");
    msg_Err( p_filter, "no image planes" );
    return NULL;
}
fmt_in = p_pic->format;
fmt_out = p_pic->format;
fmt_out.i_width = p_pic->format.i_width * p_sys->f_scale;
fmt_out.i_height = p_pic->format.i_height * p_sys->f_scale;

fmt_out.i_chroma = VLC_CODEC_BGRA;

p_sys->p_proc_image = image_Convert( p_sys->p_image, p_pic,
        &(p_pic->format), &fmt_out );

p_sys->p_to_be_freed = p_sys->p_proc_image;
i_planes = p_sys->p_proc_image->i_planes;

for( int i = 0; i < i_planes; i++ )
{
    sz = cvSize(abs(p_sys->p_proc_image->p[i].i_visible_pitch /
                    p_sys->p_proc_image->p[i].i_pixel_pitch),
            abs(p_sys->p_proc_image->p[i].i_visible_lines));

    p_sys->p_cv_image[i] = cvCreateImageHeader(sz, IPL_DEPTH_8U,
            p_sys->p_proc_image->p[i].i_pixel_pitch);

    cvSetData( p_sys->p_cv_image[i],
            (char*)(p_sys->p_proc_image->p[i].p_pixels), p_sys->p_proc_image->p[i].i_pitch );
}
p_img1 = p_sys->p_cv_image[0];
frame1 = cvarrToMat(p_img1);
//Here we'll proceed Mat frame with openCV
//and convert it back ti IplImage
//p_img1 = new IplImage(frame1);
cvGetRawData(p_img1, (uchar **) & p_pic->p[0].p_pixels, NULL, &sz);

return p_pic;
}
```

So, for now, it only receives VLC picture_t, converts it to BGRA(for openCV purposes), converts it to IplImage and back to picture_t.
But, in result, comes smth messy, which I can't download here cause of low reputation ([screenshot](http://s27.postimg.org/6wbk2amqb/Screenshot_from_2015_03_19_20_53_35.png)). Would appreciate any help.

Comment: take any of that with a grain of salt. this vlc filter is 10 years old, and unmaintained. also, using opencv's deprecated c-api is a horrible idea in 2015.

Comment: as far as I know there are no other way to use vlc's pictures in openCV except doing such converting through C-Api...or have I missed something?